# Using Javascript/PhoneGap to access a txt file on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to access a text file (stored on a server) which is storing coordinates in order to parse it and store it in my PhoneGap application. I'm fairly new to javascript, but is this possible to do? I've searched around for a while and can't seem to figure it out on my own. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Molly

Answer (score 1):

You can just use XMLHTTPRequest to fetch the text, assuming that the text file is publicly accessible. Just use something like:

```
var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "TXT_FILE_URL", true);
req.onreadystatechange=function () {
    if (req.readyState==4) {
        var txt=req.responseText;
        // Do something with the text
    }
};
req.send();
```

Unfortunately, this is all asynchronous; if you need a synchronous way, try using something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the usual javascript ajax methods, as long as you also add your server to the phonegap whitelist.

If you use jQuery (http://jquery.com/), you can get the data with the `$.get()` function.

```
$.get('http://yourserver.com/path/to/data', function(text){
    alert(text); //do something with the text
});
```

But this won't work until you whitelist yourserver.com inside phonegap - see [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) for version 2.7.0.